# Finding a specific element in multiple elements in xml using XPath

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xpath

Below is my XML:

```
<Profile>
    <_nObjectID>1</_nObjectID>
    <_sObjectName>ABC</_sObjectName>
    <_sObjectType>10</_sObjectType>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <_nObjectID>2</_nObjectID>
    <_sObjectName>DEF</_sObjectName>
    <_sObjectType>20</_sObjectType>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <_nObjectID>3</_nObjectID>
    <_sObjectName>GHI</_sObjectName>
    <_sObjectType>50</_sObjectType>
</Profile>
```

I want to know what is the *_sObjectName* for *_nObjectID=2* in this group of profiles. How do we find it using XPath?

So far I tried the below:

```
string name = productsXML.XPathSelectElement("//Profile/_nObjectID").Value;
```

But the result just gave me the *_nObjectID*. How to get it's *_sObjectName* under this *_nObjectID*?

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick for you

```
var rslt = xdc.Descendants("Profile")
              .Where(x => x.Descendants("_nObjectID").FirstOrDefault().Value == "2")
              .Select(q => q.Descendants("_sObjectName"));
```

If you only want the value of `_sObjectName` i.e. `DEF` then just call for the Value like this

```
var rslt = xdc.Descendants("Profile")
              .Where(x => x.Descendants("_nObjectID").FirstOrDefault().Value == "2")
              .Select(q => q.Descendants("_sObjectName").FirstOrDefault().Value);
```

Comment: What result will the first answer give?

Comment: my coding give error.. it does not recognise the "Where" command.. How to fix this?

Comment: The First will give `<_sObjectName>DEF</_sObjectName>` and it is not recognizing the `Where` bcoz u have to include `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Hi, but I get result is "System.Linq.Enumerable"

Comment: For your info, i want in C# language

Comment: Yes dear @Coolguy it is C#.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the specifics of the library you are using. But since you asked for a xpath way to do it, i will assume that there is a full xml support.

This query will get the _sObjectName following the _nObjectId 2 :

> //Profile[_nObjectID/text()=2]/_sObjectName

Tried here http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

If you need to loop on it, i would suggest you do string formatting before passing the xpath query !